# How to compare 2 fetch array in order to set state in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem related to set State in reactjs.

I need to fetch 2 APIs, then would like to compare an object (called `team_lead`) with an object (`userProfile`). Whether an id of the object (`team_lead`) is equal with in an id of the other object (`userProfile`) or not. If 2 ids are equal, I will set the state: `auth: true`. My 'apply' button will be only displayed whether `auth: true`. My idea is the button will be only shown if the user is logged-in and the user is also a team leader.

```
export class TeamInfo extends React.Component {
   state = {
      checked_auth: false,
      team_lead:[],
      userobject: {}
   }
   componentDidMount(){
      axios
        .get(`/teams/13`)
        .then(responseData => {
          this.setState({
             teamlead: responseData.data.team_lead,
          })

        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      axios
        .get(`/profiles/?user=${userObject.user.id}`)
        .then(responseData => {
          if (this.state.teamlead.id === responseData.data[0].id) {
            console.log("tea ok")
            this.setState({
              checked_auth: true

            })
          }

        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
   }
  render(){
     return (
        {this.state.checked_auth ? <Button> Apply </Button> : <div></div>}
     )
  }
}
```

I signed in and checked. Sometimes, the "Apply" button is shown. However, most of the time, the button is hidden. Could someone help me for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are sending 2 asynchronous request. But the second depend on the first one.

you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to solve this problem.

```js
componentDidMount(){
    const firstRequest = axios
        .get(`/teams/13`)
        .then(responseData => responseData.data.team_lead)
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
      const secondRequest = axios
        .get(`/profiles/?user=${userObject.user.id}`)
        .then(responseData => responseData.data[0])
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
        
      Promise.all([firstRequest, secondRequest]).then(values => 
       if (values[0].id === values[1].id) {
            console.log("tea ok")
            this.setState({
              checked_auth: true

            })
          }
      );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, it is not working :(.
Values of 2 request are undefined. I checked those in console.log. Here is my code:
``` 
 console.log('second', secondRequest)
      console.log('first', firstRequest)
      Promise.all([firstRequest, firstRequest]).then(values => { 
        console.log('test',values); 
      });
```
In the console log, it shows:
second Promise: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
first Promise:Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
test (2) [undefined, undefined] :(

Comment: @Kevin, I just update the code. In each promise we should return value instead of setting state. Pls get my newest code

Comment: Is there anything chance to set state? Because I need to set state to do another stuffs :(. I tried to return value like this, but it seems not to work
``` 
const firstRequest = axios
        .get(`/teams/13`)
        .then(responseData => responseData.data.team_lead)
       .then(res => {
          this.setState({
             teamlead: res.data.team_lead,
          })
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    
```

Comment: You can set state directly in promise.all handler like this this.setState({checked_auth: true, teamlead: values[0]})

Comment: Thanks for your help so much. now it is working as I expect :)